# jsadebugd/jdb and running clear JVM

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, jit, jdb

Using jsadebugd or jdb it's possible to debug already running JVMs, started without any arguments. I don't understand how it's possible, because I thought, that JVM compiles bytecode in native code by JIT, and it cannot be debuged.

Can anybody explain me ?

And how such time-to-time debug affects on performance?

Comment: I wasn't aware it's possible to attach `jdb` to a JVM that was started without special arguments. Can you show how you do it?

Comment: jsadebugd => jdb -connect sun.jvm.hotspot.jdi.SAPIDAttachingConnector:pid=1234

Answer (score 2):

Notably slows performance, however only if debugger is attached and that is only possible if compiled to allow debugging (optional).